# SSRS Lable Printing

Tags: pdf-generation, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SSRS RDL that is formated to fit on a three column lable sheet. When exported to PDF the 2nd column is not populated and on the next page the 2nd column is the only column populated. This continues to happen for as much data as I have. Has anyone had any problems with this or might have an idea on where the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kinds of quirks are usually related to the margins. Make sure that the actual label area does not exceed the page size, accounting for the margins. Also, printer drivers can cause a similar issue because of content-to-page-size issues, where the report shows correct on-screen but when printing, shifts content to a new page.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I know I didn't give a lot of details but you hit the bulls eye anyway! The report is looking good now. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

This is because of page setup properties. For example if a page is set to letter size(8.5in X 11in) and   left and right margins to 1 inch. then you have adjust you report body size to 6.5 inch or below, if it exceeds above 6.5 inch, then leads to split data to other pages when exported to PDF.